# Selfish Primes Question

Tags: number-theory

Consider the series : $1,2,4,8,16,23,28,38,49,\ldots $

( number + sum of its digits numbers gives the next number and continues up to infinity )

Now, consider the primes in this series ( the first ones $2,23,101,103,107 , \ldots $)

Now, can you help with the following questions :

1) what is the reciprocal sum of primes in this series? ( my guess is around 0.7 which makes the series converges but how I can prove that ? )

2) How many consecutive primes can be found in this series? ( My guess is 7 or 8 , but still I am not able to prove this result, for example, 101,103,107 are the consecutive primes in the series )

3) It is believed that $\frac{x}{(\ln x)^2}$ roughly gives the number of twin primes and I suspect that that formula works for the number of primes in the series ( $1,2,4,8,16,23,28,38,\ldots$ )

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Where did this question come from? Are you taking a course? Doing research? Or is this just for fun?

Comment: I have a master degree in number theory. The series actually known as Kaprekar series ( Indian math high school teacher lived 1950's) . I have been searching the answers of my question almost 2 years.

Comment: 3) seems plausible, since the sum of digits of $x$ is roughly $\frac5{\ln 10}\ln x$, so the density of the sequence at $x$ is proportional to $\frac1{\ln x}$, so the density of primes in the sequence is proportional to $\frac1{(\ln x)^2}$. That would also imply that the sum of their reciprocals converges. I don't think you have a snowball's chance in hell to find the limit in closed form; I'm surprised you're hoping for that after doing a master in number theory.

Comment: I just posted only 3 questions but more interesting questions related to this series about to come.

Comment: adding my comments to 3 : It will be interesting result if the limit converges to ln2 or square root of 0.5 ?